# XCode 15 getting error of No such module 'YOChartImageKit' even framework is there in Project

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, apple-m1, rosetta

- Using pod of **YOChartImageKit** still getting error of No such module.
  (https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuqw0.png)

Below Steps are followed multiple times but not getting result.
I tried remove pod and install again.
Clean Project -> Remove DerivedData -> Open Project.

Answer (score 0):

it's likely that the 'YOChartImageKit' framework won't build. This is because it's a very old library. The podspec indicates that the minimum deployment target is iOS 7.0. Based on this (https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/728021), newer Xcode versions no longer support building for such old deployment targets.

I suggest adding the following code snippet to your podfile:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '12.0'
    end
  end
end
```

then you'll have to do a `pod install` and probably you will have to set the User script sandboxing build options to NO in your target's build settings.

I was able to successfully build it this way. However, I would like to note that this library is very old (abandonware). Please take this into consideration before using it.

Comment: Okay Thank you, I tried the same as you mentioned but am still getting errors like below.

1. Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_YOBarChartimage

2. Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: please check my update